# Matching a date between two dates in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that shows the following data (nearly a million rows):

`Select * from [WL_Table]`

| Pri_Key | Client_ID | WL_Name | WL_Ent_Dt | WL_Exit_Dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | WL 1 | 11/03/13 | 10/04/13 |
| 2 | 4321 | WL 2 | 14/03/13 | 25/03/13 |

I also have a table that has every date since the year 2000

`Select * from [Date_Table]`

| Date |
| --- |
| 01/01/00 |
| 02/01/00 |

I'm attempting to create an output that looks something like this:

| Column A | Count WL1 | Count WL2 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/03/13 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 11/03/13 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12/03/13 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 13/03/13 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 14/03/13 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 15/03/13 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

(the results table will have much higher numbers in the count column, i've just demonstrated with the 2 rows provided)

I'm struggling to work out how to join these tables together as they do not have anything that really matches. Any advice gratefully received!

I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Search for "Conditional aggregation".

Comment: Outer join the calendar table.

Comment: Actually you should select from your calendar table and left join your wl_table where it matches the date range and then just do COUNT(wl.PriKey) to get a count of non null matches

Comment: `I've tried nothing and i'm all out of ideas` that's pretty good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take `Date_Table` as your starting point since it looks like you want to return dates even where no record exists for that date in `WL_Table` then left join to your `WL_Table` you can then do a count of matching records, using case expressions to conditionally count for each `WL_Name`, e.g.

```
SELECT  dt.Date,
        CountWL1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN wl.WL_Name = 'WL_1' THEN wl.Pri_Key END),
        CountWL2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN wl.WL_Name = 'WL_2' THEN wl.Pri_Key END),
        Total = COUNT(wl.Pri_Key)
FROM    dbo.Date_Table AS dt
        LEFT JOIN dbo.WL_Table AS wl
            ON wl.WL_Ent_dt <= dt.Date
            AND wl.WL_Exit_dt < dt.Date -- Possibly "<=" if your end date is an inclusive range
-- Optionally filter your dates to return the range you are looking for
--WHERE dt.Date >= '20130310' AND dt.Date < '20230316' 
GROUP BY dt.Date;
```